Motivation behind the Piercing property in cohomological index
I was wondering that what geometrical/topological meaning it gives to study the following piercing property due to cohomological index?.
Let $A, A_0, A_1$ be three closed sets, $\varphi\in C(A\times[0,1],A_0\cup A_1)$ such that $\varphi(-u,t)=-\varphi(u,t)$, $\varphi(A\times[0,1])$ is closed, $\varphi(A\times\{0\})\subset A_0$, $\varphi(A\times\{1\})\subset A_1$; then $$i(\varphi(A\times[0,1]\cap A_0\cap A_1)\geq i(A),$$ where $i$ is the cohomological index.

And what, exactly, is cohomological index? Are you working with closed subsets of $\Bbb R$? Why have you tagged this with PDEs? A little more context would be nice (and I mean that gently - it's good for you too, since usually people won't answer very short questions)
